# Android Studio cannot show design layout after adding a view

Tags: android, android-studio, android-textinputlayout

I'm getting a rare error when I've tried to add a TextInputLayout to a simple layout for a Dialog, the editor stops to show the design mode WTF.

[image: Screen]

What's wrong? Restarting Android Studio, doesn't work.

NOTE: The exclamation on the textinputlayout is for the contrast color of the text

Comment: Did you try to rebuild the project? (or even hard-delete the build folder)

Answer (score 0):

This not a problem. The reason of this, maybe your views is not defined.

Comment: No, thank you this is not the problem